# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError)

Tags: reactjs

When I try click on my add to favourites button it comes up with this error. This only happens when a user isnt logged in (my routes for users to login aren't working so I'm not able to test both)

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property '_id' of undefined

addIntoUser
src/components/Card.js:56
  53 | 
  54 | const addIntoUser = async (event)=>{
  55 |   event.preventDefault();
> 56 |   const id = user._id;
     | ^  57 |   const title = props.title;
  58 |   try {
  59 |     const { data: newFavorites } = await apiCalls.addFavorite({id:id,title:title});
```

Obviously, I'm assuming this is because i have no users in my database but I'm wondering if this is also another error within the code

Comment: Check value `user` before use it

Comment: `const id = user?._id` or `const id = user && user._id` add check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have a user, I think your `user` variable is empty right ? The error says that `user = undefined`
Try to put a `console.log(user)` and see it by yourself.

With this code and what you say, there is not other error since you don't have user information so your user is not defined, by logic.

If you really need the id of the user var, try to defined it before like:

```
const addIntoUser = async (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault();
    // if no user defined (due to the fact that user not log in)
    if(!user)
        user = {_id:-1} // put whatever value of _id you want
    const id = user._id;
```